# When I render my image, and select composite and combined for the render view, only one of the layers is showing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I followed a tutorial on YouTube about how to make a planet in blender. Unfortunately, he didn't show you how to render it. The tutorial has a planet layer, and an atmosphere layer. Then in a compositer, I put them together but when I render with "slot 1" "composite" and "combined" in the bottom, only the planet layer shoes up. Please help soon as I am trying to do this quick. I can't seem to find any help on this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use 2 renderlayer nodes and an alpha over node I guess - but unfortunately you did not show your nodetree from compositor so It s only a speculation....